# Symfony 4 - My Wampserver Vhost doesn't work

Tags: apache, symfony, wamp

I would like to use a vHost for my Symfony 4 project.

It is at c:/wamp64/www/symbnbb

So, in my host file, I added this:

> 127.0.0.1 symbnbb.local
>   ::1 symbnbb.local

And at  %APACHEDIR%\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf, I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symbnbb.local
    ServerAlias www.symbnbb.local

    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/symbnbb/public"
    <Directory "c:/wamp64/www/symbnbb/public/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But it doesn't work, and if I go to localhost, I've this :

```
Le chemin ${INSTALL_DIR}/www pour DocumentRoot n'existe pas (Fichier c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.37/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf)
Le chemin ${INSTALL_DIR}/www/ pour <Directory ... n'existe pas (Fichier c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.37/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf)
```

Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

In your host file juste write :

```
127.0.0.1 symbnbb.local
```

In your vhost delete :

```
ServerAlias www.symbnbb.local
```

Then in your webbrowser, call "symbnbb.local", it should work.